# Ionic 4 tabs placement

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm trying to change the placement of the tabs to top in ionic 4, but it's not working. Here is what I used: `tabbarPlacement="top"` according to [ionic docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs)

```
<ion-tabs tabbarPlacement="top">
  <ion-tab label="Home" icon="home" href="/tabs/(home:home)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="home"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="About" icon="information-circle" href="/tabs/(about:about)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="about"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Contact" icon="contacts" href="/tabs/(contact:contact)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="contact"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Attribute name is `tabbar-placement` change `tabbarPlacement` to the earlier one

Comment: I have tried it too, but not working

Comment: They have changed the ion-tabs in latest beta release (16). please use the below answer code. it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thing there are two ways to set tabs in a top of page:

1- first way by using slot= "top", (maybe you want to change top position)

```
  <ion-tab-bar slot="top">
    <ion-tab-button tab="schedule" href="/app/tabs/(schedule:schedule)">
      <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Schedule</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="speakers" href="/app/tabs/(speakers:speakers)">
      <ion-icon name="contacts"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Speakers</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="map" href="/app/tabs/(map:map)">
      <ion-icon name="map"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Map</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="about" href="/app/tabs/(about:about)">
      <ion-icon name="information-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>About</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

  <ion-tab tab="schedule">
    <ion-router-outlet name="schedule"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab tab="speakers">
    <ion-router-outlet name="speakers"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab tab="map">
    <ion-router-outlet name="map"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab tab="about">
    <ion-router-outlet name="about"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

2- the second way as ionic 3

```
 IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {

      tabsPlacement: 'top',

    }, {}
  )
```